# Appium: launching an app without using package name and activity

Tags: android, appium, ui-automation

I am creating an automation test and facing the problem in one part where I have to launch one other app.
The problem is that we can't use package name and activity name to launch the app. So what I thought is to use the below steps to launch the app:

1. Launch Application List
2. Search for the app with App ID, if not found swap right or down and search for the app
3. Once the app is found, click and launch it

Can anyone tell if this is do-able in Appium? If yes, then How?

Thanks in Advance.

Comment: Why can't you use package name and activity name to launch the app?

Comment: Hi Vinod,  There is a variant of Android Enterprise called Android for Work which creates the 2 instances of App on the device. I want to access the second instance which is not accessible. When we use package/.activity, it launches the first instance only.

Comment: I have the same problem. I had asked the question for this long back. There is way to launch the app through command prompt by specifying the profile name. But appium does not provide that feature for automation.

Comment: I found the answer to the launch app if there are two instances of the same app one in Normal Device mode and another one in Work mode. First we have to find if the device is running multiple users. If that case, check all the user ids and utilize these ids to launch the package. In case, anyone is still facing, please comment here. I'll add the details answer.